# How to display empty dates with dateInput() in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I display the birthdate of people in a shiny app using dateInput(). When nobody is selected, the value of this input field needs to be set to empty, or NULL. I tried 
     value = "",
     value = " "
     value = NULL

but none of them works. The content of the field sets itself to the current date.

How to display empty Date fields using dateInput()?

I also would like to sometimes disable the dateInput widget using  shinyjs::disable(), but this function seem to be unable to disable the dateInput widget. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

You could use renderUI() and wrote a dynamic control. See here:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

ui.R

```
# Partial example
numericInput("ind", "individual"),
uiOutput("datecontrol")
server.R
```

Partial example

```
output$datecontrol<- renderUI({
if(!is.null(input$ind) )  date <- dateInput()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your second question, `shinyjs::disable()` should work on `dateInput()`. I just tried it and it works for me

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    dateInput("date", "Date"),
    actionButton("btn", "Disable")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$btn, disable("date"))
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `updateDateInput()` and supply 'NA' as the `value` argument\parameter

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dateInput("date", "Date"),
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    updateDateInput(session = session, inputId = "date", value = NA)
  }
)
```

See [reference](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/updateDateInput.html)